# AutoMapper Convention Based System

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map my ViewModel classes to web service DTO objects. The ViewModels uses the following convention:

```
CustomerViewModel 
OrderStatusViewModel
```

The WCF classes DTO has the following convention:

```
Customer
OrderStatus
```

Also, what if the WCF classes DTO has the following convention:

```
CustomerDTO 
OrderStatusDTO
```

The question is how do I map between the ViewModel and the WCF classes using AutoMapper? I want to map in a certain way that all future ViewModels and WCF classes are mapped automatically due to the above configuration.

Comment: Maybe it is just me but I don't really see a question here. I see you making some statements about your naming convention but what it the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote about this sometime back. Check 'er out if you'd like: http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/01/the-big-boy-mvc-series-part-22-whoop/

Add a reference to **Automapper**

Create a base **ViewModel** class:

```
public abstract class MappedTo<T>
{
    public MappedTo()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap(GetType(), typeof(T));
    }

    public T Convert()
    {
        return (T)Mapper.Map(this, this.GetType(), typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Create a **ViewModel class** that inherits from the aforementioned base. Specify which DTO you'd like to map your ViewModel to:

```
class AddressViewModel : MappedTo<Address>
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper should handle the rest:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AddressViewModel addressVm = new AddressViewModel
    {
        Line1 = "555 Honolulu Street",
        City = "Honolulu",
        State = "HI"
    };

    Address address = addressVm.Convert();

    Console.WriteLine(address.Line1);
    Console.WriteLine(address.City);
    Console.WriteLine(address.State);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you can create another ViewModel base calss that allows you to pass in your own **TypeConverter**:

```
public abstract class MappedTo<T, TConverter>
{
    public MappedTo()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap(GetType(), typeof(T)).ConvertUsing(typeof(TConverter));
    }

    public T Convert()
    {
        return (T)Mapper.Map(this, this.GetType(), typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Then, you can convert from your ViewModel to your DTO however you see fit:

```
public class AddressConverter : TypeConverter<AddressViewModel, Address>
{
    protected override Address ConvertCore(AddressViewModel source)
    {
        return new Address
        {
            Line1 = source.Line1 + " foo",
            City = source.City + " foo",
            State = source.State + " foo"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! But can I somehow tell AutoMapper that my convention is that viewmodel will have the same exact name but the word "ViewModel" at the end. like CustomerViewModel (viewmodel) and Customer (class). So, that Automapper can automatically resolve all the mappings.

Comment: @azamsharp -- I don't think so. I might be wrong, but you have to tell AutoMapper which two classes you want to map. You could use a T4 template to autogenerate those mappings based off of convention, but that seems unnecessary. Why not do "CustomerViewModel : MappedTo<Customer>" like I've done above? Is that too much of a pain? Cheers, E

Comment: Question: In the approach above you can convert a ViewModel to a Model but how do you go other way. How do you convert a Model representation into a ViewModel so it can be displayed on the screen.

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a nice way to have the ViewModel received the mapped type as a parameter and populate itself.  This system seems awesome and should be added natively to Automapper

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this: mvmmapper.codeplex.com
I wrote a tool for Visual Studio that generates the mapping for you.

Read the examples to get an idea of what the tool does and then decide to write your own tool or use an existing one...

Edit: Have a [look at this code](http://mvmmapper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52907#888219) it is from the MVMMapper and being generated. It might give you an idea.

Comment: The question is stated above! How do I map between ViewModel and WCF classes?

Comment: Thanks but I have to use AutoMapper!

Comment: Ah, yes I noticed that after you added your question.